# poll.then is not a function stawpoll API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `node.js` with the module `discord.js` and [strawpall](https://github.com/m3talstorm/strawpoll) module. The `discord.js` module has nothing to do with the error I believe, The code is as follows:

```
const strawpoll = require('strawpoll')

var poll = strawpoll.create({
    title: 'My first poll',
    options: [
        'wow',
        'awesome',
        'amazing',
        'nice'
    ],
    multi: false,
    dupcheck: 'normal',
    captcha: false
})

poll.then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

the error is poll.then is not a function

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry when it was edited by someone it got removed,

Its, poll.then is not a function

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the example on the library. strawpoll.create returns an object, not a promise.

Comment: what do you expect here to work ?? you can log poll...

Comment: @EliR Would you know how to make it work?
Sorry if its too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found out how to fix your issue.

First of all, uninstall the current strawpoll with npm

`npm uninstall strawpoll`

Then, [download the .zip from GitHub](https://github.com/m3talstorm/strawpoll/archive/master.zip)

Extract the zip into node_modules and rename it "strawpoll"

Then, you need to install 2 things, request-promise, and cheerio

`npm install request-promise` and `npm install cheerio`

It should then work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Works perfectly